# Having Trouble collecting location-specific hashtags in R

Tags: r, twitter

I'm having trouble recording tweets using streamR in R.  I am looking to record all tweets that have the string "hello" in them, using USA as the boundary.  I think it is returning all tweets with hello AND all tweets in the USA, where I want all tweets with "hello" occurring in the USA.

```
filterStream("test.json", track="hello", timeout = 12,locations=c(-124.39,25.82,-66.94,49.38), oauth=twitCred)
```

Can someone solve this for me?  I've tried to look up how to fix it but I can't find any answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've specified `locations=` correctly.

[image: region map]

What makes you think that's not working. Your code looks almost exactly like one of the examples from the `filterStream` help page

```
## capture tweets mentioning the "rstats" hashtag or sent from New York City
  filterStream( file="tweets_rstats.json", track="rstats",
      locations=c(-74,40,-73,41), timeout=600, oauth=my_oauth )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe in the example you gave it captures any tweet mentioning rstats in addition to any tweets coming out of New York City, meaning any and all tweets coming form NYC, not just the ones mentioning rstats. I'm looking for how to make an "and" argument instead of an "or."